# Plupload with iOS only works for new photos, not for camera roll

Tags: ios, image-uploading, plupload

I am using plupload 1.5.8 in order to upload image files which works great except for iOS.

On iOS 9.2.x it is not possible to upload from the camera roll, but only from the camera with a fresh picture. I do get the message that the file format is not supported.

- Files taken directly with the camera can be uploaded
- Screenshots can be uploaded as well from the camera roll, but not images taken with the camera.
- The same image that can not be uploaded from the camera roll, can be uploaded from Google Drive

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly fixed: the media type filter contained the "jpeg" format, but the white space between the comma and the format might have caused this problem.